# What should I do? In SpriteKit swift it says: Type 'GameScene' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate'?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, game-center

I was coding in SpriteKit swift till I got this error saying, "Type 'GameScene' does not conform to protocol 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate' ". What should I do? The error is on the line that says class GameScene. (The error isn't that I don't have a closing bracket, because my closing bracket is below, which I didn't show) :

```
import SpriteKit
import GameKit
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let Enemy :UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
static let SmallBall : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let Mainball :UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate {

    var Mainball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MainBall")
    var redmain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var greenmain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var darkred = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var orange = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var yellow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var lightblue = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var blue = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var purple = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var pink = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
    var origin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "white")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement this method somewhere

```
gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_:)
```

see apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKGameCenterControllerDelegate/gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:)

Answer (score 0):

You declare that `GameScene` conforms to `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`, but you haven't implemented all the methods necessary.

You need to implement [`gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKGameCenterControllerDelegate/gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:) in your class.

Comment: Well how am I supposed to know? You haven't posted it.